# Me da el error Trying to get property of non-object in cap36.php on line 43

Tags: php

La línea 43 de ese php es:

```
<tr>
<td>Área</td>
<td><h3><?echo utf8_encode($capitulos->area); ?></h3></td>
</tr>
```

Estoy usando php 5.6

Comment: me temo que vas a tener que añadir más código. ¿De dónde sale `$capitulos`? ¿Qué estructura tiene esa variable?

Comment: Simple, $capitulos no es un objeto. Sin mas código no podemos aportar nada mas.

Comment: Evita usar `utf8_encode` configurando a un más alto nivel, por ejemplo: el documento HTML, la configuración de PHP, o la conexión y/o los datos de la base de datos. De lo contrario te verás obligado a depender de `utf8_encode` siempre. Imagínate que tienes cientos de variables y a todas tengas que aplicar `utf8_encode`...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está diciendo ese error es que `$capitulos` no es un objeto.

Puedes usar un `var_dump()` o `print_r()` para comprobar si `$capitulos` es un objeto o no y si lo es, cuáles son sus propiedades.

```
<?php var_dump($capitulos) ?>
```

o

```
<?php print_r($capitulos) ?>
```

Por otro lado, semánticamente $capítulos me sugiere muchos capítulos, puede que sea un array de objetos y por eso te esté lanzando dicho error. De todas formas, con ambas funciones que te he mencionado, podrás ver si es un array, un objeto (que ya te digo que no), un array de objetos, un objeto de arrays... (Hay muchas combinaciones posibles)